# Worklight HTTP Adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

When you create a Worklight HTTP adapter in Worklight Studio it spits out some files. Where on the Linux Server do those files go?

Does the HTTP adapter get loaded on the Worklight Console with the app?

It also specifies port 80 in a document I saw, does that port have to be the port of the worklight server instead?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Worklight adapter contains two basic files:
1. impl.js - containing the definition of your methods
2. xml file that contains declaration of methods

When HTTP adapter is deployed on local server it creates a .adapter file in the bin folder and that is the only file that has to go on the server.

It uses port 80 for default http calls, if your services use some other port you can use that too.

Comment: oh great. That helps. So the Adapter is uploaded when the app is uploaded on the console?

Comment: Your adapter has to be uploaded separately.  When you build it, it creates a ".adapter" file that you can upload via the Worklight Console.  Adapters aren't included in the ".wlapp" file because (among other reasons) they can be shared by multiple applications.

Comment: yes @patbarron, thanks I meant .adapter file only. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: pat - that makes sense. but when you go to upload your app it says upload app or adapter. You upload the app and adapter separate?

Comment: yes, different adapters makes different .adapter files and your app and related environments are created with .wlapp extensions. "your-appname"-all.wlapp file in bin folder will upload your app with all environments.